# Error message "is used by another process"?

Tags: c#

Although the process is working I get the info:
Access denied. And this happens when I add the action to assign the Value ReaderValue. When it is not added everything works fine. What could be wrong ?

```
private void cb_ReportCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!FirstLoad)
    {
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[2].ToString()))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand com = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                /*com.CommandText = @"SELECT SUM(Amount_Current_quarter) 
                                  FROM qryEmployeeCostsPerRev 
                                  WHERE Bereich=""" + strDepartment + @""" 
                                        AND Vorname_Name=""Unallocated"" 
                                        AND Cost_Cat_Name=""" + cb_ReportCategory.SelectedValue + @"""";*/
                com.CommandText = "sp_EmployeeCostsperRev";
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("Dept", strDepartment);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("CostCat", cb_ReportCategory.SelectedValue);

                Debug.Print(com.CommandText);

                con.Open();
                OleDbDataReader reader= com.ExecuteReader();

                if(reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while(reader.Read())
                    {
                        ReaderValue = reader.GetDouble(0);   
                    }
                }
                reader.Close();
                lblAmountValue.Text = Convert.ToString(ReaderValue);

            }

        }
```

This is the "StoredProcedure" (in Access they are Queries )

```
 PARAMETERS [DEPT] Text ( 10 ), [CostCat] Text ( 20 ); 
 SELECT SUM(NAV_TOTALS_Per_Rev.Amount_current_quarter) AS Amount 
 FROM (ReportCostCategory as t1 INNER JOIN NAV_Acc_Mapping ast t2 
      ON t1.Cost_Cat_Name = t2.Report_Category ) 
      INNER JOIN ([FTE Werte] t3 
          INNER JOIN NAV_TOTALS_Per_Rev t4 ON t3.Kostenstelle = t4.Dimension_CostCenter_Value) 
      ON t2.Account_No = t4.Account_ID 
 WHERE BEREICH=[Dept] AND Cost_Cat_Name=[CostCat] 
                      AND Vorname_Name="Unallocated";
```

Comment: Do you close Access when you run this code?

Comment: Hi, yes the application is closed

Comment: when I would replace ReaderValue Assignment in the loop by the lable text assignment than it would work again. But in this case it doesn't let me convert the reader value to int or double.

Comment: Could you show the SQL for _sp_EmployeeCostsperRev_?

Comment: 'PARAMETERS [DEPT] Text ( 10 ), [CostCat] Text ( 20 );
SELECT SUM(NAV_TOTALS_Per_Rev.Amount_current_quarter) AS Amount
FROM 
(ReportCostCategory as t1
   INNER JOIN NAV_Acc_Mapping ast t2 ON t1.Cost_Cat_Name = t2.Report_Category
  ) INNER JOIN 
([FTE Werte] t3 
  INNER JOIN NAV_TOTALS_Per_Rev t4 ON t3.Kostenstelle = t4.Dimension_CostCenter_Value) ON t2.Account_No = t4.Account_ID
WHERE BEREICH=[Dept] AND Cost_Cat_Name=[CostCat] AND Vorname_Name="Unallocated";'

Comment: Moved to the question itself. Do not put code like text in comments. It is unreadable and unformattable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... by the lable text assignment than it would work again.

That means Column 0 is not mapped to a double. It should probably be GetInt32() or GetDecimal().

Use the debugger to find out what the exact value and type are.

Or `Debug.Print(reader[0].GetType().Name)`

That leaves that the exception is way off. I'm not sure what causes that. Maybe this is a follow-up error from trying to load the errormessage form the resouces.

Comment: Now it is not saying anymore the access to the file is denied, but the specified cast is not valid. But I have turned ReaderValue from Double to decimal or int before I ran the code again.

Comment: Is there any threading that you are not showing us?  Task.Run() ?

Comment: Although I don't really understand what the problem was it is now working. With debug.print I was informed that the type was double (as in the beginning defined) and after re-conversion to double it worked.